# React Router Path Parameter Disappears After Page Reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am encountering a pretty weird problem with react-routerv6.
My Routes are like this

```js
 <Routes>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
        <Route
          path="/project/:id"
          element={
            <PrivateRoute>
              <SpecificProjectPage />
            </PrivateRoute>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
```

Now the path parameters are working fine until I reload the page. The following image recreates the error.

[image: Error Recreation]

The path parameter disappears on reload and the route is matched to the last route.

**What I have done till now to fix**

I tried installing the latest react-router version. Tried uninstalling react-router and react-router-dom and reinstalling only react-router-dom.

**Edit - 1**

Here Private Route is Basically a utility component that redirects to the main page if the user is not authorized.

Here is its code

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  let { user } = useAuth();
  return user ? children : <Navigate to={'/'} />;
};
```

And Not Found Page is a component rendered on wild card routes as there are no matches for /project in Routes

Here is the code for `<NotFound />` component

```js
export default function NotFound() {
  return (
  <Flex
   direction="column">
    <Heading
      >
        404
      </Heading>
      <Text fontSize="18px" mt={3} mb={2}>
        Page Not Found
      </Text>
      <Text color={'gray.500'} mb={6}>
        The page you're looking for does not seem to exist
      </Text>

      <Button
        colorScheme={'cyan'}
        variant="solid"
        onClick={() => {
            window.location.href = '/';
        }}
      >
        Go to Home
      </Button>
  </Flex>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code that would redirect to `"/project"` in your app? What is `PrivateRoute` doing? How are you running your app locally? This seems more likely to be an issue with how you are serving the app than it is with anything from `react-router-dom`. `react-router-dom` doesn't return 404s. Is that 404 page something the app is rendering, the `NotFound` component? Can you edit your post to include all relevant code? See [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese I have edited the question, to bring all those details into it.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe with the code you've provided. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-brattain-26u22i?file=/src/App.js:136-192) of your code. Feel free to fork this sandbox and add in more of your *actual* code to see if you can reproduce the issue. If you can then please post back here a link to your sandbox that we can inspect and debug live.